# Matplotlib plot has slanted lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot projections of coordinates onto a line, but for some reason, Matplotlib is plotting the projections in a slightly slanted manner. Ideally, I would like the (blue) projections to be perpendicular to the (green) line. Here's an image of how it looks with sample data:

[image]

As you can see, the angles between the blue lines and the green line are slightly obtuse instead of right. I tried playing around with the `rotation` parameter to the `annotate` function, but this did not help. The code for this plot is below, although the data might look a bit different since the random generator is not seeded:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prefs = {'color':'purple','edgecolors':'black'}
X = np.dot(np.random.rand(2,2), np.random.rand(2,50)).T
pts = np.linspace(-1,1)
v1_m = 0.8076549717643662

plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],**prefs)
plt.plot(pts, [v1_m*x for x in pts], color='lightgreen')

for x,y in X:
    # slope of connecting line
    # y = mx+b
    m = -np.reciprocal(v1_m)
    b = y-m*x

    # find intersecting point
    zx = b/(v1_m-m)
    zy = v1_m*zx

    # draw line
    plt.annotate('',(zx,zy),(x,y),arrowprops=dict(linewidth=2,arrowstyle='-',color='lightblue'))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the unequal axes which makes it look like they are not at a right angle. Use `plt.axis('equal')` to have equal axis spans on x- and y-axis and a square figure with equal height and width. `plt.axis('scaled')` works the same way. As pointed out by @CedricZoppolo, you should set the equal aspect ratios before `plt.show()`. As per docs, setting the aspect ratio to "equal" means

> same scaling from data to plot units for x and y

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

# Your code here
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Choosing a square figure is not necessary as it works also with rectangular figures as

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
# Your code here
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually setting the axis to equal should be done before the `plt.show()` not after as stated in this answer.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo: Aah I  use JuPyter notebook where I don't use plt.show. Sorry. Let me correct

Comment: @CedricZoppolo: I acknowledged you in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The blue lines not being perpendicular is due to axis not being equal.

You just need to add below line before `plt.show()`

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Below you can see the resulted graph:

[image]